# get a query from Sqlite database and save it in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite

first question here.
I want to get a query from SQLite and put it in a javascript variable.
Here is the code:

```
var nombremuseo = function(nummuseo, successCallback){
    db.transaction(function(transaction){

            tx.executeSql(("Select Museo FROM BseseMuseos WHERE      No_Museo=?"),[nummuseo],
                function(transaction, results){successCallback(results);}, errCallback);

        });
        document.GetElementbyId("Ntitulo").Value = nombremuseo.results;
    };
 nombremuseo(nummuseo);
 alert(nombremuseo);
```

thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `alert(nombremuseo);` this is just a function reference?

Comment: that would be the result of the function, like "museum N" or something like that

Comment: Negative, the function has not been invoked with `()` so you are just alerting the reference to the function. Your function also does not return anything, so even if you did call `alert(nombremuseo())` it would yield `undefined`

Comment: So how can I make the functin returns a value from the database?

Comment: You're going to have to look into promises, or google "how to return from an ajax call" (the result is good information) because this db transaction is most definitely async